# Download video even if direct link access restricted by .htaccess in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to download video from server in ios.

These videos is restricted by .htaccess, so that If I use direct link (i.e. http://www.dmain.com/video.mp4) it will not give me video content.

I can set filter as such if useragent is iOS or referral is something then let them access direct video link. but in iOS, I could not find such information to put in .htaccess for filtering.

Can anybody help me on this to keep restriction and download in iOS app?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [NSMutableURLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsmutableurlrequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html) especially to `setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:`
with this method you can add/change any HTTP headers.

Comment: Thanks dear. "User-Agent" header field helped me to resolve this issue.I was not aware about its format for native app. It is something like "Appname/Appversion darwin..."